# How to do scrollTop and toggleClass with Javascript and not jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **jQuery** you can use method `toggleClass` and `scrollTop` but I´m trying to figure out how to do this with javascript.

I have a fixed `<header>` menu that I´m resizing when you scroll the window. So I want to add `class="small"` to the header with the help of javascript.

I have figured out the **jQuery** code:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    $("header").toggleClass("small", $(document).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

But I want to write this in javascript.
Below is what I´ve tried with so far but I´m stuck, any help appriciated:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName(body);
    if (body > 100) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('header').classList.toggle('small');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will track if the user scrolls, and if they are 100px down the page, add the class small to all `<header>` tags.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
  var className = 'small';
  for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
    if (el[i].classList) {
      if (window.scrollY > 100)
          el[i].classList.add(className);
      else
          el[i].classList.remove(className);
    } else {
      // IE Fix
      if (window.scrollY > 100)
          el[i].className += className;
      else
          el[i].className = str.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+className+"\\b","gi"),"");
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/p6NmD/2/)

If on the other hand you only have one `<header>` tag, you could add an id to it like so `<header id='header'>`, and run the following code. It will me a bit faster, but honestly you won't notice either way.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var className = 'small';
  var el = document.getElementById('header');

  if (el.classList) {
    if (window.scrollY > 100)
      el.classList.add(className);
    else
      el.classList.remove(className);
  } else {
    // IE Fix
    if (window.scrollY > 100)
      el.className += className;
    else
      el.className = str.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+className+"\\b","gi"),"");
  }
}
```

Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/fMZdE/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! It works ok in Firefox (little bit shaky) but not so well in safari, IE and chrome.. How come?

Comment: What OS and safari/chrome version are you running? Works great for me (chrome 29)

Comment: I have 5.1.7 safari and chrome 29. In Chrome the menu flimmers when scrolling but it scrolls ok and in Safari the scrolling is not smooth it jumps steps. In IE the menu doesn´t scroll at all but in Firefox it´s actually great:)

Comment: Can you test this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/p6NmD/), it may be something else on your page slowing it down.

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it doesn´t work in Internet explorer. I believe its because of classList and I´ve tried to fiddle around to make it work but no luck:(

Comment: I checked your answer as solved as the IE problem is another question... Thank you for your help on this! And if you know how to solve the IE problem let me know!:)

Comment: @Karolina what version of IE? I'll take a look but unfortunately I can't test on IE. And thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: @Karolina I believe I've fixed the two versions, but unfortunately I can't test them

Comment: Thank´s for the try! But unfortunately still not resizing in IE. But it´s alright, if I can´t figure it out I´m gonna start a new thread for that issue:) @Graham Walters

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention browser compatibility so I'll assume it's IE8+

```
function handleScroll() {
    var header    = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0],
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset
                    || document.documentElement.scrollTop
                    || document.body.scrollTop;

    if(scrollTop > 100) {
        if(header.classList) { // Modern browsers
            header.classList.add = 'small';
        }
        else { // IE8-
            header.className = 'blop small'; // Assuming your header already has a class 'blop'
        }
    }
    else {
       if(header.classList) { // Modern browsers
            header.classList.remove = 'small';
        }
        else { // IE8-
            header.className = 'blop'; // Assuming your header already has a class 'blop'
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, false); // Modern browsers
window.attachEvent('onscroll', handleScroll); // IE8-
window.onscroll = handleScroll; // If the other 2 are not available which is not likely to happen if you need to be compatible with IE8+
```

You might want to consider adding an id to your header since you can have more than one in your page, easier to select :

```
<header id="blop">[...]</header>

document.getElementById('blop');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I´m going to try it out, do you mean I should change var header    = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0] to var blop = document.getElementById('blop') in the beginning? And add a id blop to header?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Of course you might want to choose a better, more meaningful id than 'blop'.

Comment: And I forgot feature detection at the end :
if(window.addEventListener)
   (... do things)
else if(window.attachEvent)
   (... do things)
else
   (... do things)